# Firebase write rule denied, cant see the issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i am having trouble with a write rule and cant seem to approach it in the right way, i would appreciate a fresh set of eyes on it to see where i am going wrong.

This is the rule snippet

```
"customMaps": {
  "$map":{
    "admin": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "newData.child('owner').val() === auth.uid"     
      },
    "lines": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "data.parent().child('admin/owner').val() === auth.uid || data.parent().child('admin/whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"      
    },
    "markers": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "data.parent().child('admin/owner').val() === auth.uid || data.parent().child('admin/whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"      
      },
     "labels": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "data.parent().child('admin/owner').val() === auth.uid || data.parent().child('admin/whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"      
      },           
      "users": {
        ".read":true,
        ".write":true        
      }
    }
}
```

This is the data submission

```
database.ref("customMaps").push({
  "admin":{
    "map":mapname,
    "title":maptitle,
    "owner":uid
  }
}).then((snap) => {
  key = snap.key    
  database.ref("users/"+uid+"/maps/"+key).set({
    "map":mapname,
    "title":maptitle
  });
});
```

when ever i create a new map (the above function) i get permission denied, if i set write to true on the customMap level then it all works fine, so i know the data submits and does so with the correct information, i just cant see where it is i am going wrong.

Thanks for your time.

For Reference:

```
"$map":{
    ".read":true,
    ".write" : "newData.child('admin/owner').val() === auth.uid",
    "admin": {
```

Added the above write rule into $map as i was not actually granting permission to push the data, only the admin data.

Comment: You're trying to write to `customMaps/` instead of `customMaps/$map/admin`.

Comment: it is a push though, isnt that what the $map is?

Comment: Right, but you're trying to write to `$map` directly, and adding `admin` underneath it, but you don't have rights to write to `$map`.

Comment: so, i put a write rule in map, something like

    ".write" : "newData.child('admin/owner').val() === auth.uid"

Though, that doesn't appear to work, so i'm missing something again.

Comment: Ah sorted, Thank you @PieterLaebens, i saw where i was going wrong after writing that message.